# Download one image of multiple with php

Tags: php, html, image, download, file-get-contents

I have a page getting images from a site, but to make it slightly faster, rather then finding the URL to the images I modified the URL of their thumbnails. It works fairly well, but I have to check the extension for every image. I managed to work most of it out by using a fallback with the same URL but different extension, but the problem is now that I want to add a download button but I can't find a way to get which extension worked, and doing the download for all extensions don't work either.

How could I fix this?

Relevant code:

Main PHP:

```
                    $imgsize = array();
                    $p = "";

                    if(getimagesize($val."jpg") === false)
                    {
                        if(getimagesize($val."png") === false)
                        {
                            try{$imgsize = (getimagesize($val."gif"));}catch(Exception $e){  }
                            $p = "gif";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            try{$imgsize = (getimagesize($val."png"));}catch(Exception $e){  }
                            $p = "png";
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        try{$imgsize = (getimagesize($val."jpg"));}catch(Exception $e){  }
                        $p = "jpg";
                    }


                    print('<tr><td><a href="http://www.e621.net'.$val2.'"><object style="width:'.$imgsize[1].'; height="'.$imgsize[2].';"" id="pic" data="'.$val.'jpg" type="image/png">
                                <object style="width:'.$imgsize[1].'; height="'.$imgsize[2].';" id="pic" data="'.$val.'png" type="image/png">
                                    <img style="width:'.$imgsize[1].'; height="'.$imgsize[2].';" id="pic" src="'.$val.'gif" />
                                </object>
                           </object></form></a><form method="POST" action="./download.php/?id='.$val.'"><input type="submit" id="'.$val.$p.'" value="Download" /></td></tr>');
```

Download PHP:

```
               <?php



                    if(isset($_GET["id"]))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            $url = $_GET["id"];
                            $img = 'f:\\x.png';
                            file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url."jpg"));
                        }
                        catch(Exception $e)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                $url = $_GET["id"];
                                $img = 'f:\\x.png';
                                file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url."png"));
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    $url = $_GET["id"];
                                    $img = 'f:\\x.png';
                                    file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url."gif"));
                                }
                                catch(Exception $e)
                                {
                                    print("HELLO");
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }else
                    {
                        print("Nope");
                    }

            ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In main.php, $p contains the file extension which worked. If you send $p as a parameter in the FORM post you will be able to retrieve it in download.php

Comment: @MarkChorley Thanks, i did try that but for whatever reason `$p` does not contain anything. That's my problem... I hoped that the try/catch worked like in C# but apparently not, or i'm doing something wrong